# Azure Sphere logging

Tags: azure-sphere

For Sphere devices, we can vscode/cli to deploy, debug and see logs of the application  [[1]](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure-sphere/install/qs-blink-application?tabs=linux&pivots=cli). But later  (say I kept it running for 24 hours and comes back), if I wish to see application logs, it looks like, I don't have a way. *Is there a way to see application logs on Sphere development boards without initiating the debugger*?

To be clear, this is not about monitoring applications deployed in production  [[2]](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure-sphere/deployment/interpret-error-data). This is only about development logs on Azure Sphere development boards. An example is logcat in Android [[3]](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/logcat). The intention is to analyse long running application on Azure Sphere. We cannot keep the debugger attached forever.

Answer (score 0):

This is a late response and you've probably figured it out by now but if your Azure Sphere device is connected to a network, you can [send debug logs over a UDP socket](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure-sphere/app-notes/debug-output#obtaining-debug-output-for-a-device-not-connected-to-a-development-pc) without the need for the device to be attached to the Visual Studio debugger or even a PC.

[Here's an example application](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sphere-gallery/tree/main/UdpDebugLog) that modifies the `Log_Debug` library to send the output over UDP to a receiver application that writes the output to a "deviceLog.txt" file.